# Is it ok to say “发达的教育”或者“先进的教育”？

Tags: phrase, adjectives

可以说“发达的教育”或者“先进的教育吗？

比如：......的教育是民族兴旺的标记。

What word would be appropriate to use in the above sentence?

Comment: What's the English equivalent that you want to express? If you meant something like *higher education* that would be **高等教育**.

Comment: there are online dictionaries supplying all the necessary information, e.g. bkrs: **发达**  developed (country etc)
flourishing 2) 兴盛、进步、开展。
如：「工业发达」、「经济发达」。。。。。。
to develop **先进** advanced:
学先进 learn from the advanced
上海是中国的一个技术先进的城市。 Shanghai is a technologically advanced city.。。。。。。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please pay attention to some related collocations in Chinese:

发达的 is to describe the degree of development: **发达的系统**

> 经过几十年的不懈努力，我国已经建成了**发达的**教育**系统**。

先进的 is to describe the superiority: **先进的理念**

> 这所学校的教师们有着**先进的**教育**理念**。

教育 itself can only be evaluated in a general way, such as good/normal/bad

> 该地区的居民接受了**良好的（一般的/较差的）教育**。

The sentence you made can be:

> 发达的教育系统(的建立)是民族振兴的标志。

**Note:**

- 民族兴旺 is unconventional, and it should be 民族振兴, as we always say 振兴(中华)民族
- XXX 是 XXX 的**标志**, rather than 标记. This is also by convention.

Answer (score 2):

I think each of them will be ok.

Answer (score 0):

> *What word would be appropriate to use in the above sentence?*

Depend on you want to say 'developed' or 'advanced'

- 发达 = developed (having a strong and extensive system)
- 先进 = advanced ( having the latest technology, at the leading edge of the field)
- "发达的教育(系统)” = developed education system
- “先进的教育(系统)" = advanced education system

I think this will illustrate the difference better:

> **发达的**肌肉 = **developed** muscles
>
> **先进的**科技 = **advanced** technology

Answer (score 0):

According to me, both “发达的教育” and “先进的教育” can be used. I mean, if you use either of these two in an informal situation, we can totally understand. However, the latter one would be more appropriate. The adj "发达的" is usually used to describe muscle, economy, and brain (intelligence), while the adj "先进的" is a better match for education or technology.